# Spark Python Performance Tuning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I brought up a iPython notebook for Spark development using the command below:

```
ipython notebook --profile=pyspark
```

And I created a `sc` SparkContext using the Python code like this:

```
import sys
import os
os.environ["YARN_CONF_DIR"] = "/etc/hadoop/conf"
sys.path.append("/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python")
sys.path.append("/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.1-src.zip")
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import *

sconf = SparkConf()
conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("spark://701.datafireball.com:7077")
    .setAppName("sparkapp1")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "6g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

I want to have a better understanding of`spark.executor.memory`, in the document

> Amount of memory to use per executor process, in the same format as JVM memory strings

Does that mean the accumulated memory of all the processes running on one node will not exceed that cap?  If that is the case, should I set that number to a number that as high as possible?

Here is also a list of some of the properties, is there some other parameters that I can tweak from the default to boost the performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does that mean the accumulated memory of all the processes running on
>   one node will not exceed that cap?

Yes, if you use Spark in YARN-client mode, otherwise it limits only JVM.

However, there is a tricky thing about this setting with YARN. YARN limits accumulated memory to `spark.executor.memory` and Spark uses the same limit for executor JVM, there is no memory for Python in such limits, which is why I had to turn YARN limits off.

As to the honest answer to your question according to your standalone Spark configuration:
No, `spark.executor.memory` does not limit Python's memory allocation.

BTW, setting the option to SparkConf doesn't make any effect on Spark standalone executors as they are already up. Read more about `conf/spark-defaults.conf`

> If that is the case, should I set that number to a number that as high as possible?

You should set it to a balanced number. There is a specific feature of JVM: it will allocate `spark.executor.memory` eventually and never set it free. You cannot set `spark.executor.memory` to `TOTAL_RAM / EXECUTORS_COUNT` as it will take all memory for Java.

In my environment, I use `spark.executor.memory=(TOTAL_RAM / EXECUTORS_COUNT) / 1.5`, which means that `0.6 * spark.executor.memory` will be used by Spark cache, `0.4 * spark.executor.memory` - executor JVM, and `0.5 * spark.executor.memory` - by Python.

You may also want to tune `spark.storage.memoryFraction`, which is `0.6` by default.

Comment: Please clarify your second to last paragraph. How did you come to the calculations 0.6, 0.4 and especially 0.5 taken by python

Comment: @javadba, 0.6 is spark.storage.memoryFraction (default, https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/configuration.html), 0.4 is (1 - 0.6), and 0.5 for Python is my expectation to my use case (in the worst case you may expect 0.6*2 memory usage for Python or even more, so 0.5 is a pure empirical value for my environment).

Comment: Let us consider using numpy and some python machine learning libraries that use native code. Does all that memory come from spark.executor.memory - or just from the O/S OUTSIDE of spark? Thanks!

Comment: @javadba, Yes! spark.executor.memory covers only Java part of Spark.

Comment: Thanks for these inputs - it is quite helpful. I have upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean the accumulated memory of all the processes running on
>   **one node** will not exceed that cap? If that is the case, should I set
>   that number to a number that as high as possible?

Nope. Normally you have multiple executors on a node. So spark.executor.memory specifies how much memory *one* executor can take.

You should also check spark.driver.memory and tune it up if you expect significant amount of data to be returned from Spark.

And yes it partially covers Python memory too. The part that gets interpreted as [Py4J](https://www.py4j.org/) code and runs in JVM.

[Spark uses Py4J internally](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals) to translate your code into Java and runs it as such. For example, if you have your Spark pipeline as lambda functions on RDDs, then that Python code will actually run on executors through Py4J. On the other hand, if you run a rdd.collect() and then do something with that as a local Python variable, that will run through Py4J on your driver.