# Spark, How can add more storage memory?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Hy,

I have many times this error when I use a biggest dataset and I'm using MlLib (ALS)

The dataset have 3 columns (user, movie and rating) and 1.200.000 rows

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (116722 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

My machine has now 8 cores, 240Gb RAM and 100GB Disk (50Gb free)

I want add more storage memory and more executors and I set (I'm using spyder IDE)

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "40g")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory","20g")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores","8")
conf.set("spark.num.executors","16")
conf.set("spark.python.worker.memory","40g")
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize","0")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

But I still have this:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

How I'm launching Spark (PySpark - Spyder IDE)

```
import sys
import os
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()


os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="C:/Apache/spark-1.6.0"
sys.path.append("C:/Apache/spark-1.6.0/python/")

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "25g")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory","10g")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores","8")
conf.set("spark.python.worker.memory","30g")
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize","0")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Result

```
16/02/12 18:37:47 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/02/12 18:37:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/02/12 18:37:48 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2136)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2136)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2136)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16/02/12 18:37:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: rmalveslocal
16/02/12 18:37:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: rmalveslocal
16/02/12 18:37:48 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(rmalveslocal); users with modify permissions: Set(rmalveslocal)
16/02/12 18:37:48 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 64280.
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.10.5.105:64293]
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 64293.
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\rmalveslocal\AppData\Local\Temp\1\blockmgr-4bd2f97f-8b4d-423d-a4e3-06f08ecdeca9
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/02/12 18:37:49 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/02/12 18:37:50 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/02/12 18:37:50 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.10.5.105:4040
16/02/12 18:37:50 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/02/12 18:37:50 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 64330.
16/02/12 18:37:50 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 64330
16/02/12 18:37:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/02/12 18:37:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:64330 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 64330)
16/02/12 18:37:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the running mode (standalone, YARN, Mesos) you are using but I assume you use the standalone mode (for one server)

There are three concepts that play here

- Worker node - a host that runs one or more executors
- Executor - a container that hosts tasks
- Tasks- a unit of work that runs in an
  executor (parts of stages that together form a job - both these terms
  are not important for this discussion)

The default in standalone mode is to allocate all available cores to an executor. In your case you also set it to 8 which equals all your cores. The result is that you have one executor that uses all the cores and since you also set the executor memory to 40G you're only using a fraction of your memory for ti (40/240)

You can either increase the memory for the executor to allow more tasks to run in parallel (and have more memory each) or set the number of cores to 1 so that you'd be able to host 8 executors (in which case you'd probably want to set the memory to a smaller number since 8*40=320)

Comment: Thanks. My idea it was 1 core for each worker, and 2 executors inside worker node but if I understood correctly I was wrong and the best combination it is: conf.set("spark.executor.cores","1"), conf.set("spark.num.executors","8"), conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "40g"). Am I correct?

Comment: 8*40 is too much (320 and you only have 240) you probably want spark.exeutor.cores =8 and spark.executor.memory=180/190G (you'd get concurrency from 8 tasks running in the same executor and less overhead for interprocess comm) you need to keep memory aside for the OS and for python (you set that to 40G)

Comment: @ Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz thank, and because this my spark.num.executors is 8 right? because I have 8 cores and 8 executors, correct? (one executor that uses all the core)

Comment: num cores can be 8 (or empty since it uses all by default in standalone mode) I don't remember a num.executors config but even if there is it wouldn't affect here - you have one that uses all the machine

Comment: I change the configuration but I still have the same problem and my storage memory didn't change (511.1 MB like my figure above in the question). Why I change the memory for 2Gb and the spark didn't recognize?

Comment: 2G? you should set it higher since unless you're running with multiple executors it will be divided by the workers also since you're running  python  you should keep some of the memory for that.

Comment: also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757117/spark-python-performance-tuning

Comment: Thanks for you patience @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz, but I really don't understand why I change spark configuration (now I have, conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "25g"), conf.set("spark.driver.memory","10g"), conf.set("spark.executor.cores","8") and conf.set("spark.python.worker.memory","30g"), but I still have 1 executor and 511.1MB of storage memory like the picture above. (I try to change the executor cores to 4 and 16 and still the same) :/

Comment: maybe you should update the question with more details on how you are launching Spark

Comment: it seems like you've set your IDE to run spark in local mode (-master local[4] or something similar) this means that everything is hosted in the driver and all the configurations are meaningless (since it is already set)

Comment: because this error? "Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path" ? thks @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz